# Access-Control-Allow-Origin erro com XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, cors

Olá, estou tendo o seguindo erro:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Já pesquisei e a solução que encontro é de adicionar:

```
        request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Porém, mesmo assim o erro persiste. Se eu executar a aplicação com o Cors desligado, funciona normalmente. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'https://www.URLAPI.com/api/v3/PARAMETRO);

    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');

    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Obrigatorio API
    request.setRequestHeader('access_token', 'MEUTOKEN'); //Obrigatorio API

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            if(request.status === 200){
            console.log('Status:', this.status);
            console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
            console.log('Body:', this.responseText);

                                console.log(request);

            }else{
                console.log("Erro");
                console.log(request);
            }
        }
    };

    request.send();
```

Projeto Angular 7 (WEB).
Só consigo acessar o dado que preciso quando executo o chrome com o CORS desativado.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

Comment: Tem que liberar o CORS no servidor, foi lá que você alterou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solução:

- Como o servidor da API que eu estava trabalhando não estava retornando o protocolo CORS e o navegador estava realizando o bloqueio da comunicação, após muita procura encontrei a solução no link: [Utilizando servidor Proxy para realizar a comucação.](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/73/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin-error-with-xmlhttprequest-jquery-ajax-)

[Link do servidor que trata o CORS](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)

Este intermediário trata o protocolo CORS e consegue comunicar com a API que preciso. O código fica:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.URLAPI.com/api/v3/PARAMETRO);


request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Obrigatorio API
request.setRequestHeader('access_token', 'MEUTOKEN'); //Obrigatorio API

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if(request.status === 200){
        console.log('Status:', this.status);
        console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log('Body:', this.responseText);

                            console.log(request);

        }else{
            console.log("Erro");
            console.log(request);
        }
    }
};

request.send();
```

Comment: Testei o mesmo código com outra API e sem o intermediador, e funcionou corretamente. Ou seja, a API não trabalha com o protocolo de SEGURANÇA CORS.

Answer (score 0):

> "Com a implementação do CORS um domínio permite comunicação com outro
>   de forma livre, independente do método da chamada (GET, POST, PUT ou
>   DELETE) contanto que o domínio de destino tenha especificado esse tipo
>   de comunicação.
>
> Geralmente essa configuração é feita no lado da API e cada framework
>   tem sua forma de configuração. A parte importante é a inclusão do
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin no header da reposta da API.
>
> Então, em um cenário bem simples, sua aplicação JS cliente em
>   dev.meudominio.com.br faz um request para a API (normalmente numa
>   chamada AJAX) para o servidor api.meudominio.com.br. A resposta da API
>   deve incluir no header da resposta o Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
>   http://dev.meudominio.com.br deixando claro para o navegador que ele
>   aceita requests originados somente desse domínio."

https://medium.com/@alexandremjacques/entendendo-o-cors-parte-8331d0a777e1

Veja o exemplo de solicitação:

```
GET /recurso.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://dev.meudominio.com.br/
Origin: http://dev.meudominio.com.br/
```

E a modelo de resposta da API:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2013 19:36:00 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 35
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dev.meudominio.com.br
```

Se o conteúdo de **Origin** for idêntico ao de **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** a comunicação é permitida pelo navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava fazendo um GET e o jQuery funcionava e o meu XMLHttpRequest não. Fiquei com raiva, mas descobri o que acontecia entrando no código do jQuery. Então, pra quem tiver esse problema eu consegui resolver adicionando no headers

```
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');
```

Foi só ISSO! E eu tive que remover os seguintes códigos (não sei o motivo)

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```